# App can't be moved to SD Card , Option not available

Tags: applications, internal-storage, app2sd

I've installed a app called PyDroid 3 from Play Store, but  I don't have much space available on my internal memory so i wanted to move the app to SD Card. But Move To SD Card option is available on this app.

Using Android 5.1 on Samsung J2

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the app manifest using an app like [Manifest Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer) and search for [android:installLocation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install)

| [android:installLocation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) attribute | Can app be moved to External SD ? |
| --- | --- |
| Internal Only | NO |
| Not declared | NO |
| `auto` or `prefer external` | Yes |

Note: This is for unrooted devices

Related [Google Play store asks to uninstall apps on sd card to free up space for new installations](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/190687/131553)