# Vodafone smart prime 7 SD card issue

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, sd-card, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

I recently got a Vodafone Smart Prime 7 smartphone. I want to extend the internal storage of the phone to 32 gb using a MicroSD card.

When I insert the card, the phone detects it "New SD card detected". Then i try to setup the card and choose "Use as internal storage".
Then it starts "Format as internal storage". I choose "Erase and Format".

Then it starts "Formatting SD card". It takes some time but then it finishes and asks me to move data. As the same time i get a notification on top saying - "SD card unexpectedly removed"

So on the "Move data now" i choose "Move" and get a message - "Not Enough storage space". After sometime i get a notification - "Could not move data. Data is in original location". Now ig i go to Settings > Storage and USB - I see "SD Card - Checking"

When i remove the SD card from the phone and put it into the PC it gets mounted as 2 drives. One is 16 mb and the other rest of the space.

How can i fix this? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: How does it go if you do not choose "Format as Internal"? Unless there's a solid reason for you to be converting it to adopted storage, you should be good with keeping it as external.

Comment: My intention was to have it as internal since all apps will be installed and data would reside in this storage. Or ist it also possible to do it keeping it as external ?

Comment: See the adoptable-storage tag (added to your question) wiki. It's more of a trouble for a bunch of other reasons as you would read

Comment: ok seems like lot of issues. Even if i use it as external storage can i change the default using storage to be the SD card?

Comment: Adding the SD card as external storage and making it the default save location as SD still installs apps in the internal storage

Comment: Please tag the person if you want them to respond. Yes. For a reason, see this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/191116/131553

Comment: @beeshyams - there is no android:InstallLocation for me in the manifest viewer

Comment: So, didn't the second bullet point explain what it means if not declared. Please  READ carefully