# Determine android:installLocation in Play Store BEFORE install

Tags: applications, google-play-store, external-sd

I'm familiar with moving apps from internal to external memory. In fact I have to with the limited internal memory I have.

Some apps don't allow that. I know it's the `android:installLocation` line.  I try to avoid the apps that don't allow moving to the external memory. The only way I know is to install it, and try to move it. Seems like an impractical method to me.

**So, the question is: Is there a way to determine this setting before installing?**

Specs if needed. 
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S5, SM-G900V, Android ver 6.0.1, not rooted.
Computer: Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Do you mean download the apk file, unpack it, and read the file in a text viewer? Still learning about all of this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to examine the app manifest on PC to determine if the app can / cannot be moved to external SD card

Manifest declarations that determine this are explained in  my answer here [App can't be moved to SD Card , Option not available](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191114/131553). To summarize

> Only if [android:installLocation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) is set to `auto` or `preferExternal` it can be moved to external SD

For more details on reading the manifest file on PC see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4191762/10193147)